# Extracting numbers from a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I wrote a small python script in order to extract numbers from a csv file I wrote on the shell.

```
from csv import reader

def ext(fileName):
    l= []
    with open(fileName, delimiter = '\n' ) as inp:
        for row in inp:
            l += [row]
    print(l)
```

With my test file, I get:

```
['1\n', '2\n', '5\n', '3\n', '6\n']
```

How can I make clear that I am extracting numbers and not strings? (I want to store these numbers in a list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `l += [row]`, use `l.append(int(row))`. This should work